# Kafka Connect for edit/customize the message before sending it to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

As I've read from Kafka: The definitive guide book, Kafka Connect can simplify the task of loading CSV files into Kafka. But because we didn't write any code for business logic implementation (like Python/Java code), what should I do if I want to get data from CSV, and add many data from different sources to generate a new message, or even generate new data from system logs to that new message, before loading it into Kafka? Is Kafka Connect still a good approach in this use case?

Comment: I mean, we must have a phase to edit/customize the message before sending it to Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

The source for this answer is from this Stackoverflow thread: [Kafka Connect- Modifying records before writing into HDFS sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144647/kafka-connect-modifying-records-before-writing-into-hdfs-sink)

You have several options.

1. Single Message Transforms, great for light-weight changes as messages pass through Connect. Configuration-file-based, and extensible using the provided API if there's not an existing transform that does what you want. See the discussion here on when SMT is suitable for a given requirement.
2. KSQL is a streaming SQL engine for Kafka. You can use it to modify your streams of data before sending them to HDFS.
3. KSQL is built on the Kafka Stream's API, which is a Java library and gives you the power to transform your data as much as you'd like.

Comment: Without the links in what you copied, this answer is missing some context. For example "discussion here". And your question asked nothing about HDFS, so point 2 doesn't make sense